# AutoResetEvent object , waits 60 secs OR event

Tags: .net, multithreading, set, blocking, autoresetevent

Im using AutoResetEvent object to block a thread for 60 secs ,, but I would like to block it for 60 secs or AutoResetEvent.set() event

CODE :

```
global:
private readonly AutoResetEvent _signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);

blocking:
_signal.WaitOne(60000, true);

event to give signal 
_signal.Set();
```

but it alwayas waits the whole 60 secs ! even if i released the signal .

Comment: That's not possible, you must be doing something wrong in the thread that calls Set().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WaitOne()` call blocks so your `Set()` call will only fire after the timeout of `WaitOne()`. In order to wait less time you need to call `Set()` from a different thread than the one waiting.

Not entirely clear what you are trying to do.